# Angular Google maps weird forloop issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, for-loop, callback

I have a weird issue with a for loop in my angular controller:

I have an array defined like this :

```
$rootScope.places = [
    {
        name : "Sleep",
        address : "piazza navona",
        kind : "sleep",
    },
    {
        name : "Borghese",
        address : "villa borghese",
        kind : "nature",
    },
    {
        name : "Trastevere",
        address : "trastevere",
        kind : "relax",
    },
    {
        name : "Collosseo",
        address : "collosseo",
        kind: "cultural",
    }
];
```

And a geocode function with callback argument :

```
    var geocodeAddress = function(address, callback) {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            callback(results[0].geometry.location);
        } else {
            callback(-1);
            console.log("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });
};
```

If i try to geocode and add a marker for each location in my array with :

```
        for (var i = 0; i < $rootScope.places.length; i ++) {
        geocodeAddress($rootScope.places[i].address, function(latLng){
            console.log("Array len : " + $rootScope.places.length);
            console.log("var i : " + i);
            console.log("Array : " + $rootScope.places);
            console.log($rootScope.places[i].name + " at " + $rootScope.places[i].address + " geocoded");
            console.log(latLng);
            markers.push(designMarker($rootScope.places[i].kind, latLng));
        });
    }
    $scope.markers = markers;
```

> console.log("Array len : " + $rootScope.places.length);

Says 4

> console.log("var i : " + i);

Say 4 too !

So obviously :

> console.log($rootScope.places[i]);

Says undefined

I don't understand this strange behavior. Is it related to the callback function?

Thanks for your help

Max

**EDIT :**

Hi, thank you for your help.
Know I understand how the for loop works.
I tried this :

```
        function synchronousLoop(i) {
        if (i < $rootScope.places.length) {
            geocodeAddress($rootScope.places[i].address, function(latLng){
                markers.push(designMarker($rootScope.places[i].kind, latLng));
                synchronousLoop(i+1);
            });
        }
    }
    synchronousLoop(0);
```

But the only markers displayed is the first of my `$rootScope.places`

Any clue?

Thanks for your precious help.

**EDIT 2 :**

I tried tu push my markers inside a callback function:

```
        function synchronousLoop(i, callback) {
        if (i < $rootScope.places.length) {
            geocodeAddress($rootScope.places[i].address, function(latLng){
                markers.push(designMarker($rootScope.places[i].kind, latLng));
                synchronousLoop(i+1);
            });
        }
        callback && callback();
    }
    synchronousLoop(0, function() {
        $scope.markers = markers;
        console.log($scope.markers)
    });
```

Same results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually your **for** loop is working correctly.
also your **callback function** is working correctly
The problem lies in their combination..
for first iteration i=1 and geocodeAddress(1) is called
for second iteration i=2 and geocodeAddress(2) is called....and so on
geocodeAddress(1) took some time to process and till the time callback(1) is called the value of i reaches 4..

the chain of events is like:

loop i=1
geocodeAddress(1)
loop i=2
geocodeAddress(2)
loop i=3
geocodeAddress(3)
loop i=4
geocodeAddress(4)
****i=4****
callback(1)
callback(2)
callback(3)
callback(4)
the value of i for all the callbacks is 4.

hence the console log of **i** always gives 4